# Invalid class Exception is thrown from powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

I am getting the following exception from powershell console, when I try to query an Exchange server 2007 which is hosted in Windows Server 2003.

> Invalid class
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Here is the query, which I have tried
[image]

It would be great, If someone could shed some light into this issue.

Comment: Did you check [kb820847](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820847)?

Comment: Thank you very much..... Issue got solved..